# Why is sprintf returning false here?

Tags: php, printf, string-parsing

I am trying to work out why sprintf is returning false here. Can anyone shed any light?

```
sprintf( "select dog_name, date_format(meet_date, '%D %M %Y') as date, track_name, race_name, race_stakes, race_class, race_stakes, result_place, result_box, winner_name, winner_id, result_dog_trainer, race_distance
                                from dog
                                join result using( dog_id )
                                join race r using( race_id )
                                join meet using( meet_id )
                                join track using( track_id ) 
                                join (select dog_name as winner_name, dog_id as winner_id, race_id 
                                        from dog
                                        join result using( dog_id )
                                        where result_place = 1                                    
                                        ) t0 on t0.race_id = r.race_id
                                where dog_id = %d
                                    order by meet_date desc
                                limit %d", 12345, 50);
```

Comment: the `%D` in the date_format call?

Comment: awesome good spotting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have too few arguments. If you use `sprintf()` with `date_format`, you should use two `%` like this:

```
sprintf( "select dog_name, date_format(meet_date, '%%D %%M %%Y') as date, track_name, race_name, race_stakes, race_class, race_stakes, result_place, result_box, winner_name, winner_id, result_dog_trainer, race_distance
                                from dog
                                join result using( dog_id )
                                join race r using( race_id )
                                join meet using( meet_id )
                                join track using( track_id ) 
                                join (select dog_name as winner_name, dog_id as winner_id, race_id 
                                        from dog
                                        join result using( dog_id )
                                        where result_place = 1                                    
                                        ) t0 on t0.race_id = r.race_id
                                where dog_id = %d
                                    order by meet_date desc
                                limit %d", 12345, 50);
```

here's the [PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/vcq-05i)